# Create SCSS to a div inside parent, with a relation to another child div

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like to specify a CSS rule (using SASS/SCSS) for a specific div, located as follows,

```
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="first-child has-this-class">
          ......
       </div>
       <div class="second-child">
          .....
       </div>
```

I need to write a specific CSS rule to "second-child", when the first child has the class "has-this-class".

I tried to use SCSS as this, but it didn't work.

```
    .parent-div{
       .first-child{
         &.has-this-class + .second-child{
             //Write the styles here
           }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
   .parent-div{
   .first-child:has(.second-child){
         //Write the styles here
     }
   }
```

but :has() selector isn't supported by all browsers look at [can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas)

Comment: hi thank you for the answer, could you tell me if is this pure CSS or SASS?

Comment: it is a css selector, so it is available in sass, too. Sass is only an "extension"

Comment: I understand that you want to set second-child a styling when first-child has has-this-class, but that isn't possible only with html and css

Comment: can we do it with SASS/SCSS?

Comment: no, you can do it e.g. with javascript

Answer (score 0):

This code will affect both the first and second child

```css
.parent-div {
  .first-child {
    &.has-this-class,
    + .second-child {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: crimson;
    }
  }
}
```